# asp.net form submitting data to a mysql on Apache server

Tags: asp.net, mysql, apache

Basically to start with is it even possible to have a form that runs in asp.net and have it write data to a mysql database on a remote Apache web server? If so any pointers!? Not even sure really where to start researching it!

Comment: Yes it is possible. Spend a little time [searching](http://www.christianasp.net/usingmysql50withaspnet-part1.aspx) and you will find hundreds of results that are relevant to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no...

> form that runs in asp.net

Forms do not run "in" ASP.NET.

You can generate an HTML form using ASP.NET. You can submit form data to a webserver that uses ASP.NET to process the data.

> write data to a mysql database

ASP.NET has database bindings that can talk with MySQL

> mysql database on a remote

MySQL can listen on network interfaces so clients can connect over the network instead of using local sockets.

> mysql database on a remote Apache web server

MySQL can't run on an Apache server. Apache is not an operating system.

MySQL can run on a server that is also running Apache, but with the above set up, Apache would be irrelevant.

Apache could be used to run a web service (e.g. written in Perl, Python or PHP) that connects to and queries a local MySQL server. ASP.NET could make HTTP requests to that webservice.

ASP.NET could be used to generate a form with an action that points to a URL that is handled by an Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write to a database anywhere in the world so long as you can:

1. Connect
2. Authenticate
3. Communicate (in a similar language)

You just need a connection to the database with valid credentials.  You can talk to mySQL from .NET using the mySQL client.

In "theory" it's no different from a web server talking to a separate database server in the same building so long as  the above three points are facilitated.